# How to send pushnotification to Apple and Android?

Tags: c#, android, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have applied Push Sharp in my existing WCF Service (C#) to send Push notification to particular user, for this I am using Device Id of i Pad app and using that I am sending Push notification to that user, its working fine.

But now what i want is, i need to send push notification to all the user who are using the application, means i need to send the notification globally, so how can I send push notification global with out using Device Specific id, like can we send push notification based on application id or some thing like this.

Answer (score 1):

There are various Api that is provide to send Pushnotification.

You can use Api of [parce.com](https://parse.com/docs/index) or [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/) to send Pushnotification using your c# code.